# How to toggleClass an unordered list item including including children items?

Tags: jquery

In my Wordpress theme I have a multi-level mobile navigation menu. 
I've just added spans to all parent list items that when clicked, act as buttons to toggle an `.open` class on my sub-menus.

I have done this with the jQuery code below:

```
$('<span class="submenu-button">+</span>').insertBefore('nav.main-menu#mobile ul li:not(.hide-mobile) ul').parent('li');
```

I have then used the following code to make these span buttons target the next child within the list item and open the submenus by applying the `.open` class.

```
$('.submenu-button').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('open').find('nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li').toggleClass('open');
```

What I can't work out is how to target the children of the sub-menus with this jQuery. So for example, the code currently only affects `nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul`, whereas I also want it to apply an `.open` class to `nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li` and `nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li a`.

I have tried to do this in the second code above with the `.find` selector, but it's got me nowhere. I have also tried changing `.next`to `.nextAll`, but this didn't work either.

https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/13/

UPDATE:

I've managed to edit this and it seems to be partially working.

I replaced the `.find` rule with `.children` so now the code is as follows:

```
$('.submenu-button').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('open').children().toggleClass('open');
```

The sub-menu's list items are now taking their `.open` class, but the hyperlinks inside them won't. Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: It will be very easy for us if you replicate your issue on jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to include one, sorry about this. I've added it above now.